# função de verificação sempre retornando true

Tags: java, android

eu tenho um layout com vários edittext (16) e queria fazer uma verificação se foi alterado.
quando eu chamo esse layout eu carrego todos os meus edittexts com dados do banco de dados, tendo o usuário a opção de salvar/, mudar de página, sair, entre outras
queria que sempre que o usuário altere e não salva, na hora de sair daquele layout aparecesse um pop up perguntando se deseja salvar as alterações, como acontece nos programas tipo word, paint e etc.

Meu problema é que meu código de verificação sempre retorna verdadeiro independente se tem alteração ou não(true para alterações). 
vou postar o código picotado.

main:

```
buscardados();
escrevebotao();
```

...

```
btnext2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(verificacao())
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder mensagem = 
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(paginadeedicao.this);
                mensagem.setTitle("Atenção!");
                mensagem.setMessage("Deseja salvar as alterações?");

                mensagem.setPositiveButton("Sim",new      `DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {`
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        salvar();
                        acoes();

                    }});
                mensagem.setNegativeButton("Não",new      `DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {`
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        acoes();

                    }});
                mensagem.show();
```

ações do botão(ja coloquei dentro da ação do botão da caixa para que só execute realmente depois que apertar o botão para que a aplicação não altere o texto nem a localidade do cursor em outra Thread)

minha função escrevebotão

```
    private void escrevebotao() {
    etdescricao.setText(retornadado("bt"));

    et01.setText(retornadado("bt01"));

    et02.setText(retornadado("bt02"));

    et03.setText(retornadado("bt03"));

    et04.setText(retornadado("bt04"));

    et05.setText(retornadado("bt05"));

    et06.setText(retornadado("bt06"));

    et07.setText(retornadado("bt07"));

    et08.setText(retornadado("bt08"));

    et09.setText(retornadado("bt09"));

    et10.setText(retornadado("bt10"));

    et11.setText(retornadado("bt11"));

    et12.setText(retornadado("bt12"));

    et13.setText(retornadado("bt13"));

    et14.setText(retornadado("bt14"));

    et15.setText(retornadado("bt15"));



}
```

minha função retorna dado

```
    public String retornadado(String x){
    String dado = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(x));
    return dado;
}
```

minha função buscar dados

```
public boolean buscardados(){
        try{
            cursor = Banco.query("pages",
                    new String [] {"bt","bt01","bt02","bt03","bt04","bt05",
                    "bt06","bt07","bt08","bt09","bt10",
                    "bt11","bt12","bt13","bt14","bt15"}
            , null, null, null, null, null);

            if (cursor.getCount() != 0){
                cursor.moveToFirst();


            }

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception erro){
            Exibirmensagem("BANCO", "erro ao buscar no banco: "+ erro.getMessage(), "ok");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**minha função de verificação**

```
public boolean verificacao(){
    boolean flag=false;
    if(String.valueOf(etdescricao.getText())!= retornadado("bt"))
        flag = true;
    else if(String.valueOf(et01.getText())!= retornadado("bt01"))
        flag = true;
    else if(String.valueOf(et02.getText())!=retornadado("bt02"))
        flag = true;
    else if(String.valueOf(et03.getText())!=retornadado("bt03"))
        flag = true;
    else if(String.valueOf(et04.getText())!=retornadado("bt04"))
        flag = true;
    else if(String.valueOf(et05.getText())!=retornadado("bt05"))
        flag = true;
    else if(String.valueOf(et06.getText())!=retornadado("bt06"))
        flag = true;
    else if(String.valueOf(et07.getText())!=retornadado("bt07"))
        flag = true;
    else if(String.valueOf(et08.getText())!=retornadado("bt08"))
        flag = true;
    else if(String.valueOf(et09.getText())!=retornadado("bt09"))
        flag = true;
    else if(String.valueOf(et10.getText())!=retornadado("bt10"))
        flag = true;
    else if(String.valueOf(et11.getText())!=retornadado("bt11"))
        flag = true;
    else if(String.valueOf(et12.getText())!=retornadado("bt12"))
        flag = true;
    else if(String.valueOf(et13.getText())!=retornadado("bt13"))
        flag = true;
    else if(String.valueOf(et14.getText())!=retornadado("bt14"))
        flag = true;
    else if(String.valueOf(et15.getText())!=retornadado("bt15"))
        flag = true;

    return flag;
}
```

se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço demais. 
grato!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta trocar as comparações dos if's de

```
String.valueOf(et15.getText())!=retornadado("bt15")
```

por

```
! String.valueOf(et15.getText()).equals(retornadado("bt15"))
```

Você não pode comparar `String's` ou qualquer outro Objeto (salvo em casos de `autoboxing` e `unboxing`) usando o operador `==`, porque está comparando endereços de memória e não conteúdo da `String`. Logo use o `equals` da classe `String`.

Existem casos específicos em que usar o operador `==` funciona, mas somente para `String's` que estão no `Pool de Strings`.

Answer (score 2):

Tente alterar o comando

```
String.valueOf(et15.getText())!=retornadado("bt15")
```

para

```
false == retornadado("bt15").equals(String.valueOf(et15.getText()
```

talvez isso resolva.

Porém eu acho que você deveria pensar em uma estrategia diferente.
Como utilizar uma variável static ou global que é alterada para `true` quando a pessoa alterar os EditText.

Talvez isso lhe ajude como uma alternativa [addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher))